# Calculate Riemann Stieltjes Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stieltjes-integral

I need help in calculating this RS integral:

$$\int_2^5[5-x] \ \ \mathrm{d}\log[x] = \log 3.$$

Here [ ] denotes greatest integer function.

This is an exercise sum of elelments of real analysis by Raisinghania, sum $1$(vi). This is the [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cWDm7l5G_oAC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%5B5-x%5Dd(log%5Bx%5D)%3Dlog+3+solution+rs+integral&source=bl&ots=8Ahgp7Bxym&sig=mIgyfRclmOhmcOAu-KbCcV6UBzE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVwdn5lK3XAhXDL48KHV0zC6QQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%5B5-x%5Dd(log%5Bx%5D)%3Dlog%203%20solution%20rs%20integral&f=false) to this question in googlebook.

Thanks in advance! :) (Precisely I need help with integration of greatest integer function.)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to this. I am stuck with integration of greatest integer function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

I assume $\log x$ in your question denotes $\ln x$.

In your case where everything is nicely differentiable, you have
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dg(x) = \int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx,
$$
so your integral ends up
$$
\int(5-x) d\ln (x) = \int \frac{5-x}{x} dx
$$
Can you finish this?

**UPDATE**

It seems you are interested in integrating
$$
\int \frac{[5-x]}{x}dx,
$$
where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer function. For our example we will work with integrating $\int_a^b h(x)dx$ where $h(x) = [x]$. You can then use the same technique in your specific problem.

In case of the interval $(a,b)$, let $n = [b] - [a]$ and partition
$$
I = \int_a^b [x]dx
  = \int_a^{[a]+1} [x]dx + \int_{[a]+1}^{[a]+2} [x]dx + \ldots
                         + \int_{[a]+n}^{b} [x] dx
$$
and on each of the intervals, $[x]$ is now constant, so you get
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \int_a^{[a]+1} [a]dx + \int_{[a]+1}^{[a]+2} ([a]+1)dx + \ldots
                         + \int_{[a]+n}^{b} ([a]+n) dx \\
  &= ([a]+1-a)[a] + ([a]+1) + ([a]+2) + \ldots + (b - [b])[b]\\
  &= ([a]-a)[a] + (b -[b])[b] + n[a] + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\\
  &= ([a]+n-a)[a] + (b -[b])[b] + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
\end{split}
$$

**UPDATE 2**

With the new edit of your question, you are looking to compute
$$
\int_2^5 [5-x] d\log[x],
$$
with the greatest-integer function in the log under differentiation. Since $[x]$ and hence $\log [x]$ is constant almost everywhere, you cannot use the shorthand for derivatives I quoted above. The idea is that $\Delta g(x) = 0$ everywhere except 3 points at $x \in \{3,4,5\}$. In each of these places, you have $f(x) = [5-x] \in \{2, 1, 0\}$ and $\Delta g(x) = \Delta \ln [x] \in \{ \ln 3 - \ln 2, \ln 4 - \ln 3, \ln 5 - \ln 4\}$. Hence the integral becomes
$$
\begin{split}
\int_2^5 [5-x] d\log[x]
 &= \sum_k f_k (\Delta g)_k \\
 &= 2 (\ln 3 - \ln 2) + 1 (\ln 4 - \ln 3) + 0 (\ln 5 - \ln 4) \\
 &= 2 \ln 3 - 2 \ln 2 + \ln 4 - \ln 3 \\
 &= \ln 3,
\end{split}
$$
since $2\ln 2 = \ln 2^2 = \ln 4$.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me to proceed the right way. Would be a great help if you could elaborate a bit on integration of greatest integer function. Coz the integrand is not just (5-x) but it is actually [5-x] where [ ] denotes greatest integer function.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha please see the update for an example

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess it will do the job. Thanks once again for the prompt response.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha you changed the problem again, see update 2 for full solution in your new case

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Really appreciate your effort for this. :)

Comment: Sir can u also try this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512579/evaluate-rs-integral